# Error unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning while making a SOAP connection in nestJS

Tags: node.js, soap, nestjs

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventPattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { json } from 'express';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import { XmlUtils } from 'src/xml.utils';
import * as soap from 'soap';
import {product} from './product/product.model';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  XmlUtils:XmlUtils;



  constructor(  @InjectModel('product') private readonly productModel: Model<any>,) { }

  @EventPattern( "super" )
  async handleMessagePrinted(data: Record<any, any>) {
    let dataXML;
  this.insertproduct(data);  

    this.sendSoap(data);

  }

  async insertproduct(data:any) {
    stringify(data);
    this.productModel.insertMany(data);

}

async sendSoap(data:any){
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const fs = require('fs');

// example data
let url:string = 'http://soapapu.com';
let sampleHeaders = {
  'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'soapAction': 'http://soapapu.com',
};
let xml = fs.readFileSync('./product/product.xml', 'utf-8');

// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: xml, timeout: 1000 }); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
  const { headers, body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(headers);
  console.log(body);
  console.log(statusCode);
})();
}


}
```

Any ideas why I get unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 10) ?

Answer (score 0):

You get this warning because you break the promise chain three times by not waiting or returning your promises. In order to fix this, you have to await, or return every promise, or handle their rejections by calling their catch method.

Here is the fixed version of your code:

```js
// ...
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  XmlUtils: XmlUtils;

  constructor(
    @InjectModel("product") private readonly productModel: Model<any>
  ) {}

  @EventPattern("super")
  async handleMessagePrinted(data: Record<any, any>) {
    let dataXML;
    // IMPORTANT: here we want to wait for this method, because it returns a promise.
    await this.insertproduct(data);
    // IMPORTANT: we want to delegate the handle of this promise so we return it.
    return this.sendSoap(data);
  }

  async insertproduct(data: any) {
    stringify(data);
    // IMPORTANT: we want to return this promise, se the caller can wait for it.
    return this.productModel.insertMany(data);
  }
// ...
```

I suggest you to read [some guide](https://medium.com/dev-genius/how-do-differences-in-promise-chains-and-async-await-affect-your-code-logic-b85aeb566ebb) about promise-chains and the async-await functionality.